# Is it true for this specific pde , Both fourier transform and laplace transform could be used to solve it

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + f(x, t), \quad u(x,0) = g(x), \quad 0 \leq x \leq L, \quad t \geq 0$$
where $u(x,t)$ represents the concentration of a diffusing substance, $k$ is the diffusion coefficient, $f(x,t)$ is a constant source term, and $g(x)$ is the initial concentration profile along the domain.
For Laplace Transform Solution:

Step 1: Take the Laplace transform of the equation with respect to (t):
$$ sU(x, s) - u(x, 0) = k \frac{d^2U(x, s)}{dx^2} + F(x, s) $$

Step 2: Apply the initial condition (u(x, 0) = g(x)) to get the transformed initial condition:
$$ sU(x, s) - g(x) = k \frac{d^2U(x, s)}{dx^2} + F(x, s) $$

Step 3: Solve the transformed ODE for (U(x, s)):
$$ U(x, s) = \frac{g(x) + F(x, s)}{s} + \frac{A}{s}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}x} + \frac{B}{s}e^{\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}x}$$

where (A) and (B) are constants determined by additional boundary conditions.

Step 4: Take the inverse Laplace transform to obtain the solution $u(x,t)$ in the time domain./
For Fourier transform

Step 1: Take the Fourier transform of the equation with respect to (x):
$$ \frac{\partial U(k, t)}{\partial t} = -k^2 U(k, t) + G(k, t) $$

where $U(k, t)$ and $G(k, t)$are the Fourier transforms of $u(x, t)$and $f(x, t)$, respectively.

Step 2: Apply the initial condition (u(x, 0) = g(x)) to get the transformed initial condition:
$$ U(k, 0) = G(k, 0) $$

Step 3: Solve the transformed ODE for$U(k, t)$:
$$ U(k, t) = e^{-k^2t}U(k, 0) + \int_{0}^{t} e^{-k^2(t-\tau)} G(k, \tau) d\tau $$

Step 4: Take the inverse Fourier transform to obtain the solution $u(x,t)$ in the spatial domain.

If so, sorry for asking a stupid question, but why do they take in different forms?

Comment: You haven't calculated the inhomogeneous terms correctly at step 3 of your Laplace transform method. Also I'd highly recommend using different symbols for the diffusion constant $k$ and the Fourier variable $k$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, Thank you for your comment! I am more curious about that, why for this specific equation, both Transforms are able to solve it, while the majority of others couldn't.